# display jquery custom attribute in console or log

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display the jquery custom attribute in alert or console.

I tried using `console.log()` to log my custom  data attribute but its not displaying the value.

I'm trying to display this value `data-something`, here's my code:

```
    // create a UL element
var ul = $('<ul></ul>');

// add some LI elements
ul.append(
    $('<li class="bear" data-type="panda">panda bear</li>'),
    $('<li class="bear" data-type="koala">koala bear</li>'),
    $('<li class="wallaby" data-type="kangaroo">kangaroo</li>')
);

// this won't work because our UL is not in the dom yet
console.log($('.bear').length); //=> 0

// let's just pick the bears in our UL using our UL as the context
var bears = $('.bear', ul);
console.log(bears); //=> [li.bear, li.bear]

// lets loop through and see data attributes
bears.each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('data-type'));
});
//=> "panda"
//=> "koala"
```

Comment: Couldn't you just log `rowData.APPT_LOC_QUAL[k].LOCATION_CD`?

Comment: Did you really write `data - something`? That just tries to subtract two numbers. Or is that a placeholder for what you actually tried. Please show what you actually tried, we can't read your mind.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not clear. `data-something` has nothing to do with jQuery, it's a standard attribute (as all attributes beginning with `data-`). You can retrieve it via jQuery by using `$mySelectedNode.attr('data-something')`, but this would require to include your HTML code into the DOM, which is not the case here.

Comment: @Barmar: thanks for your reply....i am trying to display the value in jquery custom attribute...

Comment: In your `data-something` is not an attribute yet. It is just a string pushed into an array. So you'll either get it through string manipulation or create the DOM element and **then** get the attribute.

Comment: You still haven't showed what you actually tried, I assume you didn't really put `data - something` in your program.

Comment: After you create the DOM elements you can use `$(selector).data("something")` to get the value.

Comment: @Barmar: i am trying to put this value in jquery custom attribute statusHtmlArr.push("<li class='loc-li' value='", rowData.APPT_LOC_QUAL[k].LOCATION_CD, "'><a class='sub-detail' href='Javascript:void(0);'>", rowData.APPT_LOC_QUAL[k].LOCATION, "</a></li>");

Comment: I can see that in your code, but it doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question. That's a string, it's not a DOM element, so there are no attributes.

Comment: @Barmar: can u tell how to fix it

Comment: No, because the question doesn't make sense the way you've written it, so I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Barmar: when I tried to display the value in alert it shows undefined statusHtmlArr.push("<li class='loc-li'  data-test='", rowData.APPT_LOC_QUAL[k].LOCATION_CD, "'  value='", rowData.APPT_LOC_QUAL[k].LOCATION_CD, "'><a class='sub-detail' href='Javascript:void(0);'>", rowData.APPT_LOC_QUAL[k].LOCATION, "</a></li>");
      alert("print the value in alert" + $('li').data('test'));

Comment: Don't put long code in comments, it's unreadable. Please edit your question to show what you actually put in your application and the error message that was displayed.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve with this code? The attribute you're logging is the same thing you just added, so why don't you just log the original variable?

Answer (score 1):

You not creating html elements you are creating strings. Since strings don't have methods like .data you can not access them. Also `data-something` is `undefined`
You have to access the data property like so:

```
element.dataset
```

Since you are not pushing html elements you can not access these attributes.

#### Create elements

```
var el = document.createElement('li');
el.setAttribute('class','loc-li');
el.dataset.something = rowData.APPT_LOC_QUAL[k].LOCATION_CD;
console.log(el.dataset.something);
```

Comment: @user2475135 I don't understand the question but you can do this for testing only and not push the element

Comment: I understood the main question but did not understand the question in the comment.
you can create your html objects this way with  `.createChildnode`